# Trim whitespace from multiple lines

Tags: python

I tried to trim whitespace in python using `s.strip()` like this, but it's only working on the first line:

**Input:**

```
   a
    b
```

**Output:**

```
a
    b
```

How do I get it to trim whitespace from multiple lines? Here's my code:

**Code:**

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    text_file = open("input.txt", "r")
    s = text_file.read()
    s = s.strip()
    text_file.close()
    with open("Output.txt", "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs because `string.strip()` only strips the trailing and leading whitespaces, it does not strip the whitespaces in the middle.

For the input -

```
   a
    b
```

And doing `text_file.read()` .

The actual string representation would be -

```
'   a\n    b'
```

`s.strip()` would strip the trailing and leading whitespaces , but not the `\n` and spaces in the middle, hence you are getting the multiple lines and the spaces in the middle are not getting removed.

For your case to work, you should read the input line by line and then strip each line and write it back.

Example -

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open("input.txt", "r") as text_file, open("Output.txt", "w") as out_file:
        for line in text_file:
            out_file.write(line.strip() + '\n')
```

Answer (score 12):

Split the lines, strip each, then re-join:

```
s = text_file.read()
s = '\n'.join([line.strip() for line in s.splitlines()])
```

This uses the [`str.splitlines()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines), together with the [`str.join()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to put the lines together again with newlines in between.

Better still, read the file line by line, process and write out in one go; that way you need far less memory for the whole process:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as infile, open("Output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.strip() + '\n')
```

Comment: The `infile` `outfile` technique is so pretty. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
for line in s.splitlines()
```

to iterate over each line and  use `strip()` for them.

Comment: I got this error:  `File "convert.py", line 5, in <module>
    for line in text_file.splitlines():
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'splitlines'`

Comment: I believe you did something wrong. Let me edit and post complete code

Comment: @RockLee: that's because the `text_file` object is not the string; Himanshu meant to use `s.splitlines()`.

Comment: Thanks Martijn for correcting me. @RockLee Did you get it now?

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, there is also `textwrap.dedent()`,
which e.g. allows to write multi-line strings indented in code (for readability), while the resulting strings do not have left-hand side whitespaces.
For example as given in https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent

```
import textwrap

def test():
        # end first line with \ to avoid the empty line!
        s = '''\
        hello
          world
        '''
        print(repr(s))          # prints '    hello\n      world\n    '
        print(repr(textwrap.dedent(s)))  # prints 'hello\n  world\n'
```